# ActiveMQ network of brokers with proper load balancing in queues and without message duplication in topics

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

I have two activemq brokers(two master/slave pairs) connected using network connector.
In queue level i need a **proper load balancing** of messages across brokers (conduitSubscriptions=false).
In topic level there should not be any **duplication of messages**(conduitSubscriptions=true).
Should i create two network connectors one for queues and one for topics.

```
    <networkConnectors>
        <networkConnector name="n_w_for_queues" userName="xxxx" password="xxxx" duplex="true" conduitSubscriptions="false" 
        uri="masterslave:(tcp://localhost:61616,tcp://localhost:61610)">
            <excludedDestinations>
                <topic physicalName=">"/>
                <queue physicalName="Consumer.*.VirtualTopic.>"/> 
            </excludedDestinations>             
    </networkConnector>
        <networkConnector name="n_w_for_topics" userName="xxxx" password="xxxx" duplex="true" conduitSubscriptions="true" 
        uri="masterslave:(tcp://localhost:61616,tcp://localhost:61610)">
            <excludedDestinations>
                <queue physicalName=">"/>
            </excludedDestinations>
        </networkConnector>
```

**Desired result:**
Requires queue messages with proper load balancing and topic messages without duplication.

Answer (score 0):

Above mentioned configurations works fine.
A network connector for queues with **conduitSubscriptions="false"** and another network connector for topics with **conduitSubscriptions="true"** will provide the desired results.